# Is the order in which you place stuff inside the head section important?

Tags: html, css, background, stylesheet, head

**Is the order in which you place stuff inside the head section important?**

Here's the thing:

I've got an HTML file with a couple of CSS stylesheets applied, and they're working just fine!

The thing is that I now want to add a background image with a very specific formatting.

1st - I tried adding that code to the main CSS stylesheet but it didn't work... (white bg/image doesn't load)

2nd - I then tried adding it to a 2nd stylesheet. It still didn't work!

3rd - Lastly I tried putting it in its own stylesheet! Still didn't work!

There must be a conflict somewhere... (I've got quite a bit of JavaScript and a lot of CSS) but unfortunately I can't post the code here :( If anybody knows of a common mistake that might be causing this, feel free to say something, if not that's fine...

And that's fine because if I place the background CSS code inside the head section IT WORKS!!!

So, my question is does it matter if I place it above or below the CSS stylesheets' links?
I'm asking this simply because it's a background image that might take a couple of seconds to load and it must load completely before the rest of the content appears.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters differently for different things.

In the case of CSS, the order matters only in that later rules of the same specificity get applied later in [the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

This means that swapping two adjacent `<link>` elements could cause rule B to override rule A instead of vice versa.